# jQuery script works just for one button on the product catalog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony, twig

I have a product catalog and I want to save on localstorage the products selected by the user. 
The jquery script only gets the first product on each page on each click... it simply ignores the rest of the products, and the console prints the same object.

Here is my HTML+TWIG code

```
 {% for products in pagination %}

                    <div class="product col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 hero-feature">

                      <div id="{{attribute(products ,'id')}}"  class="product thumbnail">

                        <img id="prodImage"  class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="{{attribute(products ,'image')}}" style="width:150px;height:150px" >

                        <div class="product caption">

                            <h4 id="prodPrice"  class="product pull-right"><b>{{ attribute (products, 'price') }}Lei</b></h4>

                            <h4 id="prodName"   style="height:100px;width:200px;">

                                <a id="prodLink" 
                                    href="{{ attribute (products, 'affiliatelink') }}" 
                                    target="_blank">{{attribute ( products, 'name') }}</br></a>

                            </h4>

                           </div>

                              <div class="add-to-cart" class="product" >

                                   <button id="buttonProd" class="oneButton btn btn-danger " value="Save" type="button">Adauga</button>

                              </div>

                    </div>                         

                  </div>

                {% endfor %}
```

Here is the jquery script

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>                                            
    <script type='text/javascript' defer="defer">
    $(document).ready(function() {     
    var prodId = $('.thumbnail').attr("id");

               $("#buttonProd").on("click", 'button', function(event){
                 event.preventDefault();

         var products =
                 {
                   prodID    :$('.thumbnail').attr("id"),
                   prodName  :$('#prodName').text(),
                   prodPrice :$('#prodPrice').text(),
                   prodImage :$('#prodImage').attr('src'),
                   prodLink  :$('#prodLink').attr('href')
                 };


                         localStorage.setItem('products-' + prodId, JSON.stringify(products));

var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products-' + prodId));
console.log('retrievedObject: ', retrievedObject);
         });

});

       </script>
```

How can I make the script take each product proprieties on click. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to save the product in localStorage on clicking of corresponding button right?

for that instead of binding click event via jquery, put it in html and move the click code to a function saveProduct()

**HTML:**

```
<button id="buttonProd" class="oneButton btn btn-danger " value="Save" type="button" onclick="saveProduct({{attribute(products ,'id')}})">Adauga</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function saveProduct(event, prod_id){
event.preventDefault();
         var products =
                 {
                   prodID    :prod_id,
                   prodName  :$('#'+prod_id+' #prodName').text(),
                   prodPrice :$('#'+prod_id+' #prodPrice').text(),
                   prodImage :$('#'+prod_id+' #prodImage').attr('src'),
                   prodLink  :$('#'+prod_id+' #prodLink').attr('href')
                 };


   localStorage.setItem('products-' + prod_id, JSON.stringify(products));

var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products-' + prod_id));
console.log('retrievedObject: ', retrievedObject);
         });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery, the assumption is made that all ID's will be unique.  Since you're repeating "#buttonProd", JQuery will only select the first one to bind the action to.  If you want to bind to multiple elements, you'll either have to give each button a unique ID or use some other selector to attach your jQuery functionality.

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) for the ID Selector:

> Calling jQuery() (or $()) with an id selector as its argument will return a jQuery object containing a collection of either zero or one DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have eluded to you should be using a different selector. I recommend simply adding a descriptive class to each element you wish to grab data from.

```
<div class="products">
     <div class="product">    
         <div class="productName">First Product</div>

         <div class="productPrice">5.00</div>
     </div>

     <div class="product">    
         <div class="productName">Second Product</div>

         <div class="productPrice">4.00</div>
     </div>

     <button id="buttonProduct">Log Product Info</button>
 </div>
```

If you notice in the above HTML each div that contains a product's name or a product's price shares the same class `productName` and `productPrice` respectively. In addition each container class for each product has the same class as well: `product`.

This will allow us to utilize the JQuery class selector `$(".")` to iterate over each `product` container. We do this using the `.each()` function. We use the `.find()` function to locate `productName` and `productPrice` in each iteration of the loop.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {     

    $("#buttonProduct").click(function(){

    var products = [];

    // Notice the dot in $(".product") that is the class selector
    // the .each iterates over every element that matches the preceding selector
    $(".product").each(function(){

        products.push({
          // The .find() selects an element inside $(this)
          // that matches the parameter (either .productName or .productPrice
          productName : $(this) .find('.productName').html(),
          productPrice : $(this).find('.productPrice').html()
        });

     });

     console.log(products);

   });

});
```

For a working example of this check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssy0e1vq/2/). (I noticed you had console.log() in your code so that's where I output the result.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did tried the almost the same idea to make it work yesterday... but something in my markup was wrong for sure.

Comment: @BanicaAlexandru sure thing. I'm glad you found an answer that worked for you though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `#buttonProd` from an id to a class. An id is only supposed to appear once on a page, so jQuery will only apply it to one. Change it to a class in your markup and your script and it should work fine. Same for `prodName`, `prodPrice`, `prodImage`, and `prodLink`. Anything that will be going inside the loop needs to be a class, and any id should be unique, like you have `{{attribute(products ,'id')}}`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, helps me a lot in my future development on this project :) (strategy for the markup:)) . I did go with  Kishore solution.